# Mapstruct 1.3.0.Final version is generating wrong code generation for optional collection getter fields

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

We have a POJO class with Optional getter fields. The mapstruct 1.3.0.Final generating wrong code for the Optional collection field.

We have ProgramAggregate POJO which contains Collection of Program (Collection) and it is an Optional getter type.

When we run with mapstruct 1.2.0.Final, we are seeing proper code generation.
But the same code with 1.3.0.Final generating wrong code. It is not generating the Collection mapping method for Optional Collection getter methods.
[Generated code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQlPj.jpg)

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = false, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ProgramAggregate {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Collection<Program> programs;

    public Optional<Collection<Program>> getPrograms() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(programs);
    }


}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = false, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "_type")
public class Program {
    String name;
    String number;


    public Optional<String> getName() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(name);
    }

    public Optional<String> getNumber() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(number);
    }

}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = false, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ProgramResponseDto {
    Collection<ProgramDto> programs;

    public Optional<Collection<ProgramDto>> getPrograms() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(programs);
    }

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = false, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "_type")
public class ProgramDto {
    String name;
    String number;
    String oldNumber;

    public Optional<String> getName() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(name);
    }

    public Optional<String> getNumber() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(number);
    }

    public Optional<String> getOldNumber() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(oldNumber);
    }

}

@Mapper(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN,
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE)
public interface IProgramMapper extends IOptionalMapper, IDefaultMapper {
    ProgramResponseDto map(ProgramAggregate programAggregate);

    ProgramDto map(Program sourceProgramDto);

    Collection<ProgramDto> mapPrograms(Collection<Program> sourcePrograms);



}
```

Result:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-10-12T13:10:32+0530",
    comments = "version: 1.3.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class IProgramMapperImpl implements IProgramMapper {

    @Override
    public ProgramResponseDto map(ProgramAggregate programAggregate) {
        if ( programAggregate == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProgramResponseDto programResponseDto = new ProgramResponseDto();

        **Collection<ProgramDto> collection = fromOptional( programAggregate.getPrograms() );**
        if ( collection != null ) {
            programResponseDto.setPrograms( collection );
        }

        return programResponseDto;
    }

    @Override
    public ProgramDto map(Program sourceProgramDto) {
        if ( sourceProgramDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProgramDto programDto = new ProgramDto();

        if ( sourceProgramDto.getName() != null ) {
            programDto.setName( fromOptional( sourceProgramDto.getName() ) );
        }
        if ( sourceProgramDto.getNumber() != null ) {
            programDto.setNumber( fromOptional( sourceProgramDto.getNumber() ) );
        }

        return programDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ProgramDto> mapPrograms(Collection<Program> sourcePrograms) {
        if ( sourcePrograms == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Collection<ProgramDto> collection = new ArrayList<ProgramDto>( sourcePrograms.size() );
        for ( Program program : sourcePrograms ) {
            collection.add( map( program ) );
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Below is the error after maven build.
Error:

**[ERROR] //mapstruct_latest_example/target/generated-sources/annotations/IProgramMapperImpl.java:[21,57] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds**
[ERROR]     equality constraints: java.util.Collection
[ERROR]     upper bounds: java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object

Comment: The code generated without a mapping method.
**Collection<ProgramDto> collection = fromOptional( programAggregate.getPrograms() );**

Comment: How did the code look like in 1.2? How does the fromOptional method look like?

Comment: The code generated without a mapping method. 
**Collection<ProgramDto> collection = fromOptional( programAggregate.getPrograms() );  [With Mapstruct 1.3.0.Final]**
It should generate like below :
**Collection<ProgramDto> collection = mapPrograms(fromOptional( programAggregate.getPrograms() ));  [With Mapstruct 1.2.0.Final]**

Comment: fromOptional method is:

 **default <T> T fromOptional(final Optional<T> o) {
        return o.orElse(null);
    }**

Answer (score 0):

Issue:
Allow generic of generics in types when matching

e.g. method signature such as

```
<T> T fromOptional(Optional<T> optional)
```

when T resolves to another generic class such as Collection

This might be resolved in **mapstruct 1.4.2.** version.